# Set Helvetica as font in beamer title?

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

How can I set Helvetica as font in

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{size*={32pt}{38.4pt},series=\bfseries}
```

Comment: (I am using xelatex)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `family`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Old Standard} % just to make it distinguishable from Helvetica

\newfontfamily\helveticalike{TeX Gyre Heros}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size*={32pt}{38.4pt},series=\bfseries,family=\helveticalike}

\begin{document}

\title{A title in Helvetica}

\author{Who}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The example sets an absurd main font just for it being distinguishable from the title font.

[image]

Comment: `
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Old Standard" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.5 \setsansfont{Old Standard}
                               % just to make it distinguishable from Helvetica
`

This does not work for me. 

Mebus

Comment: @Mebus Use another font that you know you have. As I wrote, it's just a very different font to emphasize where Helvetica is used.